# ansible get result from role and append to a list

Tags: ansible

I have a play like this

```yaml
---
- name: List images in ACRs
  any_errors_fatal: true
  hosts:
    - localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    acrs: ["registry1", "registry2"]

  tasks:
    - name: list repos
      with_items: "{{ acrs }}"
      include_role:
        name: list_docker_image_repos
      vars:
        registry_name: "{{ item }}"
```

`list_docker_image_repos` will do set_fact which a list of dicts.
How can I append all the facts (from every iteration) to a list?

Or is there are different way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration put the list into a dictionary. For example, given the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/list_docker_image_repos/tasks/main.yml
- set_fact:
    docker_image_repos: "{{ ['repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3']|
                            product([registry_name])|
                            map('join', '-')|
                            list }}"
- set_fact:
    my_lists: "{{ my_lists|
                  combine({registry_name: docker_image_repos}) }}"
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    acrs: [reg1, reg2]
    my_lists: {}

  tasks:

    - name: list repos
      include_role:
        name: list_docker_image_repos
      loop: "{{ acrs }}"
      vars:
        registry_name: "{{ item }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_lists
```

gives the dictionary

```yaml
my_lists:
  reg1:
    - repo1-reg1
    - repo2-reg1
    - repo3-reg1
  reg2:
    - repo1-reg2
    - repo2-reg2
    - repo3-reg2
```

---

A dictionary is a more suitable structure for this purpose compared with a list. There are many ways how to use it. For example, you can

- extract the lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ acrs|map('extract', my_lists)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
msg:
  - - repo1-reg1
    - repo2-reg1
    - repo3-reg1
  - - repo1-reg2
    - repo2-reg2
    - repo3-reg2
```

- Use the filter *flatten* to put all items into a single list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ acrs|map('extract', my_lists)|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
msg:
  - repo1-reg1
  - repo2-reg1
  - repo3-reg1
  - repo1-reg2
  - repo2-reg2
  - repo3-reg2
```

- Use the filter *dict2items* to iterate items

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ my_lists|dict2items }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item:
    key: reg1
    value:
    - repo1-reg1
    - repo2-reg1
    - repo3-reg1

  item:
    key: reg2
    value:
    - repo1-reg2
    - repo2-reg2
    - repo3-reg2
```

- Or, use the lookup plugin *subelements* to iterate the items of the lists as well

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_lists|dict2items }}"
        - value
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item:
  - key: reg1
  - repo1-reg1

  item:
  - key: reg1
  - repo2-reg1

  item:
  - key: reg1
  - repo3-reg1

  item:
  - key: reg2
  - repo1-reg2

  item:
  - key: reg2
  - repo2-reg2

  item:
  - key: reg2
  - repo3-reg2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    acrs: [reg1, reg2]
    my_lists: {}

  tasks:

    - name: list repos
      include_role:
        name: list_docker_image_repos
      loop: "{{ acrs }}"
      vars:
        registry_name: "{{ item }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_lists
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ acrs|map('extract', my_lists)|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ acrs|map('extract', my_lists)|flatten }}"
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ my_lists|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        var: item
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ my_lists|dict2items }}"
        - value
```